# Big device for drawing and writting on it?

Tags: monitoring, presentations, drawing, graphics-tablet

I'm searching for some big device (22 inch) on which can draw, write and load some presentation file. Want to replace pan and paper with some modern device. 
Let's say that want to make instruction of physics for classroom, and instead of writing on whiteboard to write on that device (which have big advantages cause can save those materials and use it next time, also can be improved next time, etc...).

Something bigger than tablet, like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah-1EeWMvuw) (**what device is used in video**?)

Do you have some idea what to buy for those purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Cintiq has the 22HD which has 21.5 inch screen that you can see what you are writing on. It should double as a second monitor or duplicate your screen so it works just like another monitor. They also have the even larger 24HD. Both of these aer pricey though, and will put you in the hole $2000-$2500. They have a smaller 13" and 17" line too if I recall correctly. Wacom Cintiq are a big name in the graphics tablet industry, so you may be able to find other LCD tablets for cheaper but these guys have their name on the stake so they probably try to reflect that with quality.

This guy is probably using a Wacom Cintiq 22HD or 24HD